# Implementing hyperlink html in php with MySql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

For example I have a `order_number` from `MySQL` database.

The code below will print out  **Order Number:**`order_number`. I want to make a hyperlink to the `order_number`. Is it possible to do so?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '<b>'.'Order Number: '.'</b>' .$row['order_number'].'<br />';
 }
```

Is this code below correct for the `order_number` hyperlink?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '<b>'.'Order Number: '.'</b>' ."<a href="www.testpage.com/jobs/order_number">$row['order_number']</a>".'<br />';
 }
```

I'm even sure it is possible to increment each page with the new `order_number`.

i.e: `order_number` = 11111  --> `www.testpage.com/jobs/11111`

`order_number` = 22222  --> `www.testpage.com/jobs/22222`

Comment: Ah but what is the link for a specific order_number? `http://website.com/orders/order_number`, etc?

Comment: Sorry for not be specific, the link should `www.website.com/jobs/order_number`

Comment: I understand. See my solution. The `order_number` is linked within the url outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are mixed up. Try the example below. I put it on two lines to make it more readable.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '<b>Order Number:</b>';
     echo '<a href="www.testpage.com/jobs/order_number">' . $row['order_number'] . '</a><br />';
}
```

I suppose you also should place the order number somewhere in the href attribute, maybe like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '<b>Order Number:</b>';
     echo '<a href="www.testpage.com/jobs/' . $row['order_number'] . '">' . $row['order_number'] . '</a><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<b>'.'Order Number: '.'</b>' .'<a href="www.example.com/sample.php?orderNumber='.$row['order_number'].'">'.$row['order_number'].'</a><br />';
}
```

OR

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $orderNumber=$row['order_number'];
     echo "<b>Order Number : </b><a href='www.example.com/sample.php?orderNumber=$orderNumber'>$orderNumber</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You needed to link the variable in the url that you are outputting as well. To easily create the string, I bound the variable from `$row` into a new variable.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $order_num = $row['order_number']

    echo "<b>Order Number:</b>" .
         "<a href='www.testpage.com/jobs/$order_num'>$order_num</a><br />";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are accessed through double quotes and ignored in single quote cases...

Try

```
echo '<b>'.'Order Number: '.'</b><a href='www.website.com/jobs/"$row['order_number']"'>$row['order_number']</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a quote problem between ' and ".

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '<b>'.'Order Number: '.'</b>' ."<a href="www.testpage.com/jobs/order_number">$row['order_number']</a>".'<br />';
 }
```

As you can see you are using double quote when you start the link (a) tag. You should keep using the single quote.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo('<b>Order Number:</b><a href="www.testpage.com/jobs/order_number">'.$row['order_number'].'</a><br />');
 }
```

You also doesn't need to use that much quotes. You can have several string within the same quote.